# redefine uint type c++

Tags: c++, c++11

In `c++` when I try to compile the following code I get a conflicting declaration error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef uint_least64_t uint;

int main() {
    uint i = -1;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

error:

```
main.cpp:5:24: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef uint_least64_t uint’
 typedef uint_least64_t uint;
                        ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/basic_string.h:5417,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:152:22: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef unsigned int uint’
 typedef unsigned int uint;
                      ^~~~
```

I assume that conflicting declaration error is because a type declaration for `uint` already exists somewhere in the language, and I believe that the type is `uint_least32_t` because:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint i = -1;
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

returns an integer value that is (2^32)-1. Therefore is it possible in `c++` to redefine `uint` as `uint_least64_t`.

Comment: Show the rest of your code.

Comment: Question has been edited. Please let me know if there is any other information that you need.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the error message, on your platform `<iostream>` pulls in `<string>`, which pulls in `<cstdlib>`, which pulls in `<stdlib.h>`, which pulls in `<sys/types.h>`.

Looking at the source code, we can see that `<sys/types.h>` does this:

```
#ifdef __USE_MISC
/* Old compatibility names for C types.  */
typedef unsigned long int ulong;
typedef unsigned short int ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
#endif
```

The `#ifdef __USE_MISC` guard is part of the [`feature_test_macros`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) system. `__USE_MISC` is set internally if you request `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` (which is also set if you request nothing else).

Thus you should be able to bypass the problem by compiling with `-ansi` or one of the `-std=...` options (e.g. `-std=c++11`).

Answer (score 0):

`uint` is not part of standard C++.

It's quite possible that something in your codebase is introducing it, or perhaps even the C++ standard library that ships with your compiler. You might be lucky and the library has introduced `std::uint` and you're introducing that into the global namespace when you write that polluting statement `using namespace std;`.

Sadly, you can't un-`typedef` a type or hide a `class` once it's been introduced.

So you'll just have to use a different symbol.

Comment: "Sadly, you can't un-typedef a type or hide a class once it's been introduced.". i guess that means i have to change every instance of uint to uint_least64_t or a typedef of that

Comment: Ah, now you've pasted up more code, you never know, removing `using namespace std;` might fix it.

Comment: sadly, it doesn't

Comment: How about a scoped `using`? can you use that to replace the `typedef` inside a namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can not redefine the typedef symbol and will have to use different(unused) symbol.

If you want to use the same symbol you can wrap it in namespace as mentioned in this post: [Using a typedef'd uint causes error, while "unsigned int" does not...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163262/using-a-typedefd-uint-causes-error-while-unsigned-int-does-not)